# next line after printing an integer in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to print a string in a new line after printing an integer, but in my program, it prints on the same line and I don't know how to remedy it. Here is my code:

```
.data                           
.asciiz "My Name\n"                 # 0-10
.asciiz "Enter the number of times to repeat "      # 11-47
.asciiz "Enter the first number "           # 48-71
.asciiz "Enter the second number "          # 72-96
.asciiz "The sum is "                   # 97-108
.asciiz "First number is greater than the second\n" # 109
.globl main
.text
main:
    lui $ra, 0x1001     # init
    lui $a0, 0x1001     # init
    ori $a0, $a0, 0     # init
    ori $s1, $s1, 1
    addi $t4, $zero, 1  # to be used in loop
    ori $v0, $zero, 4   # to print string
    jal print       # print name    
    addi $a0, $a0, 11   # Enter num to repeat
    ori $v0, $zero, 4   # to print string
    jal print       # 
    jal read        #
    add $t0, $v0, $zero # stores amount to repeat in $t0
repeat:             # to be repeated by what the user inputted
    addi $a0, $a0, 48   # Enter first num
    ori $v0, $zero, 4   # to print string
    jal print       #
    jal read        #
    add $t1, $v0, $zero # stores first num input in $t1
    addi $a0, $a0, 72   # Enter second num
    ori $v0, $zero, 4   # to print string
    jal print       #
    jal read        #
    add $t2, $v0, $zero # stores second num input in $t2
    jal eval        #
    addi $t4 $t4, 1     # adds 1
    slt $t3, $t0, $t4   # set $t3 1 if $t0 < $t4
    beq $t3, $s0, repeat    # if $t3 = $s0 (0) then repeat
    ori $v0, $zero, 10  # to exit program
    jal print       # exits program

print:              # syscall function
    syscall         # calls system
    beq $a2, $zero, return  # if $a2 = 0 then returns early
    add $a0, $a1, $zero # puts the integer in $a1 to $a0 to be print
    ori $v0, $zero, 1   # to print integer
    syscall         # prints integer
    j return        #
return:             # returns to last jal instruction
    sub $a2, $a2, $a2   # clears $a2
    sub $a0, $a0, $a0   # clears $a0
    lui $a0, 0x1001     # re-init
    jr $ra
read:               # reads the input of the user
    addi $v0, $zero, 5  # to read input
    syscall         # reads user input
    j return
sum:                # calculates the sum
    add $a1, $t1, $t2   # integer to be print
    sub $a2, $a2, $a2   # clears $a2
    addi $a2, $zero, 1  # 1 to $a2 to print integer
    ori $a0, $a0, 97    # to print the sum is string
    ori $v0, $zero, 4   # to print string
    j print
eval:               # evaluates to go to sum or print error
    slt $s2, $t2, $t1   # $t2 < $t1
    beq $zero, $s2, sum # if $s2 is 0 then goto sum
    ori $a0, $a0, 109   # prints first num greater than second
    ori $v0, $zero, 4   # to print string
    j print
```

Here is my output:

```
My Name
Enter the number of times to repeat 3 (3 is input)
Enter the first number 4              (4 is input)
Enter the second number 6             (6 is input)
The sum is 10Enter the first number 4
Enter the second number 6
The sum is 10Enter the first number 4
Enter the second number 6
 The sum is 10
-- program is finished running --
```

Obviously, I want to print the string 'Enter the first number ' in a new line after 'The sum is 10'. The string, 'The sum is ' is printed first and then the integer, '10' is printed afterwards. After the integer '10' is printed, I want the next string to print in a new or next line. I don't know how to do this properly. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You used the `print integer` system call which of course prints `10`. Try the `print character` instead (number `11`).

Comment: @Jester I just tried it and it indeed does skip to the next line, but it doesn't print the integer.

Comment: Yeah obviously you need to use the appropriate one for the situation. If you want an integer printed on the next line, first print the line feed then print the integer. Two different system calls.

Comment: @Jester Ahh, I understand now. I just tried it out and it does work! I feel like it's 'not the proper way' to do it, but it works and I thank you for your help!

Comment: It is the proper way. The only other way would be to convert the number to a string yourself, and then you could print it in one go.